# VB.net LINQ filter on multiple columns

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, search, filter

Hi please can you advise me on the best way to achieve filtering on multiple columns in LINQ

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user] (
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[firstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[surname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[fullAddress] [nvarchar](1050) NULL
```

I would normally use SQL for this

```vb
Dim firstname as string = 'bob'
Dim surname as String = 'holdness'
Dim address as String = 'blockbuster street'
Dim Stmquery as string = 'Select * from users '
if not String.isnullorEmpty(firstname) or not String.isnullorEmpty(surname) or not String.isnullorEmpty(address) then 
Stmquery = Stmquery & "where"
end if
if not String.isnullorEmpty(firstname) then
Stmquery = Stmquery & " firstname = " & firstname
end if
    if not String.isnullorEmpty(surname) then
Stmquery = Stmquery & " surname = " & surname
end if
    if not String.isnullorEmpty(address) then
Stmquery = Stmquery & " address = " & address
end if
```

So basically if the string is empty it will show all records for that column

Can someone show me how to do this in LINQ

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have LINQ to SQL DBContext prepared, with `Users` table mapped.

You can easily extend your query, because it's not going to be executed against database until you call `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `First()`, `Last()`, etc.

```
Dim query = dbContext.Users;

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname) Then
    query = query.Where(Function(u) u.FirstName = firstname)
End If

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname) Then
    query = query.Where(Function(u) u.Surname = surname)
End If

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) Then
    query = query.Where(Function(u) u.Address = address)
End If

' query execution is here, after next line '
Dim results = query.ToList()
```